# How can I aggregate a variable according to year and country using groupby fucntion?

Tags: pandas

My variable is

> outcome_v["sfd_indx"]

and I would like to see how it change throughout years at country level (I would like to see how the mean changes for each country throughout time).

Sample of the data:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAkHq.png)

Comment: Could you please provide a sample of your DataFrame?

Comment: Please add a `sample data` and `desired output` so everyone can know what you are looking for

Comment: I guess you can just use outcome_v.groupby(['name', 'year']).mean()

Comment: In my understanding to get the mean of "sfd_indx" it should be as follows outcome_v.groupby(['name', 'year'])['sfd_indx'].mean()

Answer (score 0):

`outcome_v` here is a Dataframe.

```
outcome_v.groupby(['name' , 'year'],as_index=False).agg({'sfx_indx':'mean'})
outcome_v[['name', 'year', 'sfx_index']].head()
```